# Matplotlib interactive widget from python script

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-widget

I am adapting [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697259/interactive-matplotlib-plot-with-two-sliders) to interact with a plot using `matplotlib`'s widgets.
The way I normally work is interactive, from within `spyder` I just call a function that does the plotting.
My goal is to make an executable available to users who do not have `Python` installed, so as an intermediate step I am wrapping the functions into a script.
I have minimal experience with standalone scripts, so in a nutshell mine looks like this:

```
import various_modules
def plotting()
    ...
    plot_some_initial_stuff
    sl = Slider()
    plt.show()                <-------
    def update()
       ...
       ax.set_ydata()
       fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    sl.on_change(update)
    return()
plotting()
```

So I just define the plotting function and then call it.
I had to add the `plt.show()` command, which I do not need to have when I'm working from the `IPython` shell, otherwise doing:

```
python my_plot.py
```

would not produce anything. By adding `plt.show()`, the window shows up with the graphs I define in the initialization part. However, no interaction happens.

What is the correct way of achieving interaction when running a script like I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not know all the details, I learnt that:

- the default mode for script is [non-interactive](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode)
- this means that

  - no plot is generated until `show()` is called
  - the execution of the script does not proceed after the statement

Therefore, my call to `show()` was too early and actually blocked the definition of the `update` function and its connection to the `slider.on_change()` event.

It has been enough to move `show()` to the last line of the function definition to obtain the desired behaviour.