# Changing facecolor with matplotlib widgets

Tags: matplotlib, widget, background-color, matplotlib-widget

I'm trying to code an interactive matplotlib plot similar to the one given as answer by @Joe Kington on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697259/interactive-matplotlib-plot-with-two-sliders).

The difference is that i'm trying to make the facecolor also vary according to the changes caused by the sliders. Thus, i added some lines of code, resulting in the code below.

The facecolor indeed changes, but not as expected. Somehow the plot just accumulates the colors, resulting in a mess.

I looked for some way to erase the facecolor of the plot before updating it in the sliders_on_changed function, but no sucess.

Can anyone help me?

```
from numpy import pi, sin
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
import IPython
from matplotlib import colors


shell = IPython.get_ipython()
shell.enable_matplotlib(gui='qt')


def signal(amp, freq):
    df = pd.DataFrame(amp * sin(2 * pi * freq * t),columns = ['values'])
    df['positive'] = df['values']>0
    return amp * sin(2 * pi * freq * t),df


axis_color = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Adjust the subplots region to leave some space for the sliders and buttons
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
amp_0 = 5
freq_0 = 5
df = signal(amp_0, freq_0)[1]

# Draw the initial plot
# The 'line' variable is used for modifying the line later
[line] = ax.plot(t, signal(amp_0, freq_0)[0], linewidth=2, color='red')
ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
ax.set_ylim([-10, 10])

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green', 'red'])
ax.pcolorfast(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(),
               (df['positive'] > 0).apply(lambda x: int(x)).values[np.newaxis],
               cmap=cmap, alpha=0.3)

# Add two sliders for tweaking the parameters

# Define an axes area and draw a slider in it
amp_slider_ax  = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axis_color)
amp_slider = Slider(amp_slider_ax, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0, valinit=amp_0)



# Draw another slider
freq_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axis_color)
freq_slider = Slider(freq_slider_ax, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=freq_0)



# Define an action for modifying the line when any slider's value changes
def sliders_on_changed(val):
    selAmp = amp_slider.val
    selFreq = freq_slider.val
    df = signal(selAmp, selFreq)[1]
    
    
    line.set_ydata(signal(selAmp, selFreq)[0])
    
    cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green', 'red'])

    ax.pcolorfast(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(),
                   (df['positive'] > 0).apply(lambda x: int(x)).values[np.newaxis],
                   cmap=cmap, alpha=0.3)
    
    fig.canvas.draw()



amp_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)
freq_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)

# Add a button for resetting the parameters
reset_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
reset_button = Button(reset_button_ax, 'Reset', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')


def reset_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    freq_slider.reset()
    amp_slider.reset()
reset_button.on_clicked(reset_button_on_clicked)

# Add a set of radio buttons for changing color
color_radios_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15], facecolor=axis_color)
color_radios = RadioButtons(color_radios_ax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)
def color_radios_on_clicked(label):
    line.set_color(label)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
color_radios.on_clicked(color_radios_on_clicked)

plt.show()
```